# Entity Framework cursor based pagination

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, pagination

How to efficiently implement cursor based pagination with EF? Traditionally `Take` and `Skip` solve the common way of do it, but for scenarios where data is added and removed frequently traditional pagination is not the best way to go for.

To put things in context suppose you need to list a huge list of products, you can store last product id and go with a where clause asking for ids greater than or less than the value stored. Things get complicated when you need to provide the ability to sort based on criteria like price, date added etc where you can have equals values for many items, then greater than or less than is not enough.

LINQ has `SkipWhile` and `TakeWile` but this work over objects not over SQL, but I can go for it if a decent solution come to my mind or with a smart answer / comment. I am trying to implement graphql pagination as per Relay.js

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you find anything useful on this subject? Looking to implement the same..

Comment: Luckly for me the client was fine with pages, so I did not complete the research, but if you find anything useful, please post and I will give you the answer.